# Background Issue on Chrome Mac OSX 10.9.5

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, background

I have a website at http://www.ucsmun.co.uk that displays perfectly on Chrome on a windows machine but looks like this on Chrome on a Mac computer.

[image: Image here]

The white area cuts off half of the background image.

What do I do to fix this? I have this CSS for the background as follows:

```
   html,
     body {
     height: 100%;
   }
```

And:

```
    #headerwrap {
background: url(../img/back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top:120px;
text-align:center;
background-attachment: relative;
background-position: center center;
min-height: 700px;
width: 100%;

-webkit-background-size: 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100%;
-o-background-size: 100%;
background-size: 100%;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule to the `#headerwrap` div

```css
height: 100%;
```

If I open up devtools on your site and put it in, it works. See screenshot. There is no whitespace at the bottom of the window.

[image: Example]

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I can't tell if that's because the browser hasn't reloaded the CSS or it's not working...

Comment: It should be. See the screenshot above.

Comment: Ah so it is, must just be the old CSS still being cached. Thanks so much!